# Need help in clarifying my understanding regarding absorption and emission spectrum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, visible-light, electrons, spectroscopy

In absorption spectrum .  So , what happens here is that when white light is passed through a gas. The photons of the white light are absorbed by the electron in the gas. This means that the electron has received the required amount of energy from the white light  needed for it to jump from the ground to excited state.

Note : The gas can’t absorb every kind of light and leaves behind the one it didn’t absorb. Those ones which it didn’t absorb are formed on the screen.

In emission spectrum , the electron jumps from higher to lower orbit. So , here energy is released by the electron . Here , we can see certain colors to be formed on the screen by the electron and some not. My Q 1 here is that what forces the electron to lose energy?

Q2 would there be any difference if I used liquids and solids to be passed through white light?

This is what I have tried to understand from these two phenomenon. Please help in correcting me my Q’s and where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are asking why can't we pass light through solids and liquids right? One reason could be that specifically when you are doing the emission spectrum you need the sample to be in gaseous *as well as* in the ground state.

The ground state is to ensure uniformity in experimental values and, you know, scientists are probably more interested in the energy released from the ground state to the next energy level, than from say another level.

Using the same principal ,As for the gaseous part, my understanding is that the gaseous state is taken so that the intermolecular forces of attraction is the least. It is because these forces may also interfere with the results and so you would be needing greater amount of energy to for the same electron to go from one energy state to another. That's the first reason

Second reason could be that most of the photons are reflected rather than absorbed. [Heres the difference](https://fis.uni-bonn.de/en/recherchetools/infobox/professionals/what-remote-sensing/reflection-and-absorption#:%7E:text=Electromagnetic%20waves%20like%20the%20sunlight,surfaces%20reflect%20and%20absorb%20differently.)

Comment: No wait this question has already been asked and provided better answers over [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/382667/why-are-line-spectra-only-seen-in-gases)

Comment: Thank you but is my explanation of everything right or wrong

Comment: @SrijanM.T yes your understanding is correct to me

Answer (score 0):

The reason why electrons jump from higher to lower state is because when they're in a higher state their potential energy is also higher than usual. Thus, making it more unstable. And as everything in universe wants to have a lower potential energy (more stability) the electron comes back to it's original state. Just like a ball when placed at a desk would like to fall on the ground.